# Code breaking in if/else statement

Tags: python, calculator

I'm making a multiplicity calculator and I almost have it down, the problem is that when I ask for a number if the user gives a string input the code breaks and throws an error even though I have an `else:` for the `if` statement.

```
def Start():
    numberOneList = []
    numberTwoList = []
    multiples = 100000
    iterations = 0
    multiplicity = int(input("How many common multiplicities you would like to find between two numbers: "))

    if multiplicity > 0 and multiplicity < 100001:
        numberOne = int(input("Input the first number: "))
        if numberOne > 0 and numberOne < 100001:
            numberTwo = int(input("Input the second number: "))
            if numberTwo > 0 and numberTwo < 100001:
                for i in range(multiples):
                    mNumberOne = numberOne * i
                    numberOneList.append(mNumberOne)
                    mNumberTwo = numberTwo * i
                    numberTwoList.append(mNumberTwo)
                print("")
                print("Common multiplicities:")
                print("")
                print("Calculating...")
                print("")
                for i in numberOneList:
                    for a in numberTwoList:
                        if a == i:
                            if a != 0:
                                print(numberOne, "x", i / numberOne, "=", i)
                                print(numberTwo, "x", a / numberTwo, "=", a)
                                print("")
                                iterations += 1
                                if iterations == multiplicity:
                                    Again()
                                else:
                                    continue
                            else:
                                continue
                        else:
                            continue
            else:
                print("Invalid answer, restarting")
                Start()
        else:
            print("Invalid answer, restarting")
            Start()
    else:
        print("Invalid answer, restarting")
        Start()

def Again():
    calculateAgain = input("Calculate again? [y/n]: ")
    if calculateAgain == "y":
        Start()
    if calculateAgain == "n":
        quit()
    else:
        Again()

Start()
```

Comment: That's because an `else` statement has nothing to do with catching errors. You need to use `try/except`.

Comment: I highly advise against using recursion to run your function again... use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because you are asserting an `int` type on the user's input, without checking to make sure this is valid first. As @kindall noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461395/python-code-breaking-in-if-else-statement#comment73978663_43461395), `try/except` allows you to catch failed type assertions and handle them gracefully.  Wrapping your `int` casts with something like the following should do the trick:

```
try:
    multiplicity = int(input("How many common multiplicities you would like to find between two numbers: "))
except ValueError as e:
    print('Please input a valid number')
    return str(e)
```

(Note that instead of returning the error text, you might just repeat the prompt instead.)

Comment: Also note that you should avoid excepting the generic Exception. Use ValueError in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix for your current code is to create a function to get an input or an invalid value if its not an int

```
def input_positive_integer(message):
    while(True):
        try:
            value = int(input(message))
            if (value<=0 or value > 100000 ):
                raise ValueError("Not in range")
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Value error!! Try again!")
```

Then you can change all your inputs that receive an integer to use this function.

Notice that it will keep in loop until the value is valid.

I really suggest you to avoid recursion on that code, try using a simple while loop...